# Spring boot consume 2 rest and merge some fields

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Im new to Spring Boot and got a problem were i need  to consume 2 remote Rest services and merge the results. Would need some insight on the right approach.
I got something like this:

```
{"subInventories":[
  {"OrganizationId": 0,
    "OrganizationCode":"",
    "SecondaryInventoryName":"",
    "Description":""},...{}...],
{"organizations":[
  {"OrganizationId":0,
    "OrganizationCode":"",
    "OrganizationName":"",
    "ManagementBusinessUnitId":,
    "ManagementBusinessUnitName":""}, ...{}...]}
```

and need to make it into something like this:

```
{"items":[
{"OrganizationId":0,
    "OrganizationCode":"",
    "OrganizationName":"",
    "ManagementBusinessUnitId":0,
    "ManagementBusinessUnitName":"",
    "SecondaryInventoryName":"",
    "Description":""},...{}...]
```

got 2 @Entitys to represent each item, Organizations and Inventories with the attributtes like the JSON fields.
**EDIT**
Currently trying to get matches with Java8 stream()

```
@GetMapping("/manipulate")
public List<Organization> getManipulate() {
    List<Organization> organization = (List<Organization>)(Object) organizationController.getOrganization();
    List<SubInventories> subInventories = (List<SubInventories>)(Object) getSuvInventories();
    List<Organization> intersect = organization.stream().filter(o -> subInventories.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getOrganizationId()==o.getOrganizationId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return intersect;
    
}
```

[found this searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012725/how-to-merge-two-spring-boot-micro-services-response-in-wrapper-class) but i got many classes and I don't know if it would be better to just for each organization get the subinventories and put them in a list of maps like

```
List<Map<String,Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
//Loops here
Map<String,Object> a = new HashMap<>();
a.put("OrganizationID", 1231242415)...
myList.add(a)
```

Quite lost in what the right approach is.

**EDIT2**

Here the classes I'm using.

Organizations

```
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Organization implements Serializable{
    
    //@JsonObject("OrganizationId")
    @Id
    private Long OrganizationId;
    private Long ManagementBusinessUnitId;
    private String OrganizationCode,OrganizationName,ManagementBusinessUnitName;
    
    public Organization() {
    }
//getters setters
}
```

SubInventories

```
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SubInventories implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    private Long OrganizationId;
    private String OrganizationCode,SecondaryInventoryName,Description;
    
    public SubInventories() {
        
    }
//getters and setters
}
```

Wrapper to unwrapp consume

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Wrapper {
    //@JsonProperty("items")
    private List<Object> items;

    public Wrapper() {
    }
    
    public List<Object> getOrganization() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setOrganization(List<Object> organization) {
        this.items = organization;
    }
    
}
```

OrganizationController

```
@RestController
public class OrganizationController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @GetMapping("/organizations")
    public List<Object> getOrganization() {
        return getOrganizationInfo();
        
    }

    private List<Object> getOrganizationInfo() {
        String url = env.getProperty("web.INVENTORY_ORGANIZATIONS");
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);
        builder.queryParam("fields", "OrganizationId,OrganizationCode,OrganizationName,ManagementBusinessUnitId,ManagementBusinessUnitName");
        builder.queryParam("onlyData", "true");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth(env.getProperty("authentication.name"),env.getProperty("authentication.password"));
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Wrapper> temp = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Wrapper>() {});
        List<Object> data = temp.getBody().getOrganization();
        return data;
    }
    
    
}
```

SubInventoryController

```
@RestController
public class SubInventoryController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @GetMapping("/sub")
    public List<Object> getSuvInventories() {
    
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("this is private :(");

        builder.queryParam("onlyData", "true");
        builder.queryParam("expand", "subinventoriesDFF");
        builder.queryParam("limit", "999999");  
        builder.queryParam("fields", "OrganizationId,OrganizationCode,SecondaryInventoryName,Description");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth(env.getProperty("authentication.name"),env.getProperty("authentication.password"));
        headers.set("REST-Framework-Version", "2");
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Wrapper> subInventories = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Wrapper>() {});
        List<Object> data = subInventories.getBody().getOrganization();
        return data;
    }

}
```

where I'm right now

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private OrganizationController organizationController;
    @Autowired
    private SubInventoryController subInventoryController;
    
    @GetMapping("/manipulate")
    public Map<Organization, List<SubInventories>> getManipulate() {
        List<Organization> organizations = (List<Organization>)(Object) organizationController.getOrganization();
        List<SubInventories> subInventories = (List<SubInventories>)(Object) subInventoryController.getSuvInventories();
        Map<Organization,List<SubInventories>> result = new HashMap<Organization,List<SubInventories>>();
        for(Organization organization : organizations) {
            List<SubInventories> subInventoryMatched = (List<SubInventories>) subInventories.stream().filter( s -> s.getOrganizationId()== organization.getOrganizationId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            result.put(organizations.get(0), subInventoryMatched);
        }
        return result;  
    }
}
```

From what I understand I need to make a wrapper class for each POJO cause the response looks like this
/organizations

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "OrganizationId": 1,
            "OrganizationCode": "adasd",
            "OrganizationName": "Hotel Bahía Príncipe Sunlight Costa Adeje",
            "ManagementBusinessUnitId": 131231,
            "ManagementBusinessUnitName": "asdasfdas"
        },
        {
            "OrganizationId": 2,
            "OrganizationCode": "adadas",
            "OrganizationName": "Hadasd",
            "ManagementBusinessUnitId": 1231,
            "ManagementBusinessUnitName": "aewfrqaew"
        }]}
```

and /subInventories

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "OrganizationId": 1,
            "OrganizationCode": "asada",
            "SecondaryInventoryName": "adfasdfasdgf",
            "Description": "pub"
        },
        {
            "OrganizationId": 2,
            "OrganizationCode": "asgfrgtsdh",
            "SecondaryInventoryName": "B LOB",
            "Description": "pub2"
        }
]}
```

If used the generic one with Object I get a java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap incompatible with com.demo.model.Organization in the stream().filter and for the merge of the fields another class to get the desired

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "OrganizationId": 1,
            "OrganizationCode": "asdas",
            "OrganizationName": "adsadasd",
            "ManagementBusinessUnitId": 1,
            "ManagementBusinessUnitName": "asdasdf",
            "SecondaryInventoryName": "sfsdfsfa",
            "Description": "pub1"
        }]}
```

Tons of classes if i get lots of POJO

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly the problem is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I edited to add further info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the following from the information you provide:

- You have two Datatypes (Java classes). They should be merged together to one Java class
- You have to load this data from different sources
- Non of the classes are leading

I can provide you some example code. The code is based on the previos adoptions. This will give you an idea. It's not a simple copy and paste solution.

At first create a class with all fields you want to include in the result:

```java
public class Matched {
  private Object fieldA;
  private Object fieldB;

// Some getter and Setter
}
```

The Basic idea is that you load your data. Than find the two corresponding objects. After that do your matching for each field.

```java
public List<Matched> matchYourData() {
  // load your data
  List<DataA> dataAList = loadYourDataA();
  List<DataB> dataBList = loadYourDataB();

  List<Matched> resultList = new ArryList<>();
  for (dataA: DataA) {
    DataB dataB = dataBList.stream()
        .filter(data -> data.getId() == dataA.getId())
        .findFirst().orElseThrow();
    // Now you have your data. Let's match them.
    Matched matched = new Matched();
    matched.setFieldA(dataB.getFieldA() == dataA.getFieldA() ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse());
    // Set all your fields. Decide for everyone the matching strategy
    resultList.add(matched);
  }
  return resultList;
}
```

This is a quite simple solution. Of course you can use Tools like Mapstruct for mapping purpose. But this depends on your environment.

Comment: will look Mapstruct